# RunTime Error на DFS задаче C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, dfs

Первый раз написав решение [этой задачи](http://contest.samara.ru/ru/problemset/6161/) на привычном себе питоне, натолкнулся на ошибку TimeLimit, деваться некуда - переписал на С++, и теперь, на 15-м тесте натыкаюсь на RunTime. Собственно вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int i, j;


void DFS(int st, int n,  vector<vector<int>> &graph, bool visited[])
{
    int r;
    visited[st]=true;
    for (r=0; r<=n; r++)
    if ((graph[st][r]!=0) && (!visited[r]))
    DFS(r, n, graph, visited);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    bool *visited=new bool[n];

    vector<vector<int>> graph(n, vector<int>(n, 0));



    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if(x>0){
            graph[x-1][i] = 1;
        }
    }


    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        visited[i]=false;
    }

    bool *vis=new bool[n];
    int outlist[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        int s = 0;
        DFS(i,n, graph, visited);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(visited[j] == true){
                s++;
            }
            visited[j] = false;
        }
        outlist[i] = s;
    }


    int max = 0;
    int maxi;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(outlist[i] > max) {
            max = outlist[i];
            maxi = i+1;
        }
    }

    cout << maxi << " " << max;

    return 0;
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в функции `DFS` этот
`for (r=0; r<=n; r++)`

цикл делает одну лишнюю итерацию выходя за рамки как `graph` так и массива `visited` - непонятно почему вы там поставили знак равно !?

поменяйте на

`for (r=0; r < n; r++)`

так как индексация с нуля, значит последний элемент будет под номером `n - 1`

Comment: Эх, а я искал как раз что-то подобное у себя в коде, спасибо, глупая ошибка.

Comment: Кстати, 15-й тест прошел, но уперся я во все тот же TimeLimit) Вероятно, где-то зацикливается